# Can MKGeodesicPolyline be divided into arbitrary number of points along to the line?

Tags: swift, mapkit

Can MKGeodesicPolyline be divided into given number of points and then obtaining CLLocationCoordinate2D of each point?
Something like this:

```
let coordinate1=CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: abc, longitude: def)
let coordinate2=CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ghi, longitude: jkl)
let points=[coordinate1, coordinate2]

let myRoute=MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: points, count: points.count)
let pointsEnroute=myRoute.getEquallyDisplacedPoints(numOfPoints: 10)
```

Platform is iOS, language should be Swift.

so that I would get 10 pointsEnroute as an array of coordinates that would all by located on "myRoute"?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on: https://gist.github.com/freak4pc/98c813d8adb8feb8aee3a11d2da1373f

```
let route=MKGeodesicPolyline(points: [point1,point2], count: 2)
var coordinates=[CLLocationCoordinate2D](repeating: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid,count: route.pointCount)
route.getCoordinates(&coordinates, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: route.pointCount))
```